# How Do Generic Methods Know About Inaccessible Types? (Or "How I Lost a Dollar")

Tags: c#, generics, casting

So, we had a little bet on our team whether something would work or not.  I lost.  Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using MyNamespace;

namespace PrivateGeneric
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void WhoIsRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var store = new GenericDataStore();

            try
            {
                var data = new MyPrivateClass();
                store.StoreTheData(data);
                object theData = store.GetTheData<MyPrivateClass>();
                if (theData == null || !(theData is MyPrivateClass))
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Seann was right.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WOOOOOOOOOT!!!!! PHIL WINS!!!!!! HAHAHAHA!!!!!! PWNED!!!!!!!");
            }
        }

        private class MyPrivateClass
        {

        }
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class GenericDataStore
    {
        readonly List<object> _store = new List<object>();

        public void StoreTheData<T>(T data)
        {
            _store.Add(data);
        }

        public object GetTheData<T>()
        {
            //How does "t is T" work if T is a private type unknown to this class?
            return _store.FirstOrDefault(t => (t is T));
        }
    }
}
```

The question of why it works is highlighted in the code.  Does "is" not need to cast to T to determine whether it is in fact a T?  And does it not need the type to be accessible to do so?  Obviously that's not the case, so what mechanism does the highlighted line use to make its determination?

Comment: MyPrivateClass is not unknown. Private on classes only means that they can't be seen from another namespace, but your classes are within the same namespace..

Comment: That is simply not correct.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Comment: Updated the code to add separate namespaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think about it this way:

```
class C
{
    private const int BigSecret = 0x0BADFOOD;
    public static void M() { D.X(BigSecret); }
}
class D
{
    public static void X(int y) { Console.WriteLine(y); }
}
```

When C.M is called, D.X learns the secret and shares it with the world. The fact that BigSecret is private is irrelevant; you passed its *value* along. Code is not disallowed from seeing the *value* of a private field, it is disallowed from using the *name* of the private field. X is perfectly free to use the value of y as it sees fit; it does not do anything illegal, like trying to use the *name* of BigSecret.

Type arguments are the same way. They're logically *arguments* passed to the generic function. Of course they are not passed using the same mechanisms under the hood, but logically they're just arguments passed around that set the values of a type parameter, just like regular arguments set the values of formal parameters. If you don't want to pass around a secret private type then *don't pass it as a type argument*.

In your case StoreTheData is not allowed to use the *name* of PrivateClass, but if passed the *value* of PrivateClass, it can use it all it wants. If you didn't want it used then you shouldn't have passed it around. Same as if you didn't want BigSecret known, then you shouldn't have passed it around. A secret shared is no longer a secret.

Incidentally, we take advantage of the fact that a generic type does not do an accessibility check on its type parameters to make anonymous types work. See my article on the subject for details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I think you're confusing two separate concepts -- visibility and runtime type information.

Every struct/class has type information.  How you get that type information isn't important.  E.g. you could reflect over an assembly and dig out some private type and the `GetTheData<T>` method would still function as expected.

In this case, the `MyPrivateClass` type that you pass in is visible at the call site (as `MyPrivateClass` is nested inside your main class, and is thus visible to it).  As such, you know the type at the call site and you pass it into the `GetTheData<T>` method.

At that point, the type's information is known and is passed through as the generic type parameter.  Your code then uses that generic type parameter to do the type check.

Do this:

```
GetTheData<T>()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type information: {0}", typeof(T).FullName); 
}
```

If you call this method with the type `MyPrivateClass` -- it will print the type's name as expected.

*edited -- removed the stuff about `Type` comparisons as Eric L pointed out that there's an IL instruction for the is/as operators, and I'm not sure what happens beyond that point.  For the purposes of the question, all you need to know is that the runtime knows about types and can compare them happily enough.

Comment: So is the "is" keyword actually doing a type.Fullname comparison?

Comment: (The above comment was posted before you updated your answer.)

Comment: Phil: Check out what happens in reflector.  I'd imagine it'd be doing something like this under the covers: (t => t is T) becomes (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t.GetType()))

Comment: You would be wrong. The "is" and "as" operators have their own IL instruction that does a type check. They do not rely on reflection. See  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your private type is visible inside the class in which it is defined and so there is no scoping problem. You can also do something like:

```
public interface ISomeInterface { }

public class SomeInterfaceFactory
{
   private class SomeClass : IAnInterface { }

   public ISomeInterface Create() { return new SomeClass(); }
}
```

Now externally the `ISomeInterface` that is created is actually an instance of `SomeClass`, which you can verify through reflection even though that class is private to `SomeInterfaceFactory`.

Comment: I screwed up the bracketing on my initial post--the data store was meant to be in a separate class.  I updated the post to reflect that (and put it in a separate namespace as well).